# I can't use vector in C++ in VSCode on MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

How to use vectors without this mistake in VSCode on MacOS?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> nums = {9, 3, 7};
  // nums.push_back(9);
  // nums.push_back(3);
  // nums.push_back(7);
  cout << "hello";
}
```

```
vsc_hello.cpp:7:15: error: non-aggregate type 'vector<int>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
  vector<int> nums = {9, 3, 7};
              ^      ~~~~~~~~~
```

```
% clang
clang: error: no input files

% clang++ -v   
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

My json file:

```json
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: clang++ сборка активного файла",
      "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
      "args": [
        "-fcolor-diagnostics",
        "-fansi-escape-codes",
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "detail": "Задача создана отладчиком."
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: what standard do you use? I think you might compiling against the C++98 standard. try C++11 or newer instead using --std:c++11 for example

Comment: The official macOS clang++ instructions tell you to enable c++17 by editing tasks.json and c_cpp_properties.json: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)